# Android MediaStore get cursor position by comparing with TITLE_KEY

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am using MediaStore's media content and have a SearchView to filter the content displayed in a listfragment.

I keep a reference to the cursor(`mainCursor`) when the query string is null (which means all rows)
When user searches, i get new cursor based on the query

As per my understanding(I am very new to Cursor,DB & Contentprovider), the cursor will contain all the rows matching the query and the column to query is `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE`, so i can see matching titles in list.

```
public void doQuery(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG,"inside doQuery: "+query);
    String search = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'";
    Cursor cursorNew = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns, search , null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.SWAP_CURSOR));

}
```

Now when user presses list element, i `getPosition()` of the cursor and retrieve the `TRACK_ID` of selected item.

**My question is:** How to search the initial cursor, i.e., `mainCursor` with `TRACK_ID` got from `cursorNew` and `to get the position of the matching TRACK_ID in mainCursor?`
I don't want to `SELECT` from the mainCursor, because i want to get the position of a specific TRACK from the un-filtered cursor

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in the position, why dont you put the audio_ids in an array

```
     ArrayList<String> audio_ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        String audio_id =     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID));
        audio_ids.add(audio_id);
    }
```

and then use

```
        String audio_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID));
        position = audio_ids.lastIndexOf(audio_id);
```

This example queries playlists. The above example would give you the last position if you had duplicates. (something you perhaps had not thought about?)
I hope this gives you some ideas

Comment: For time being i m taking your suggested way, Thanks, but an unexpected behaviour; In `mainCursor` the entry is at position 276, but `lastIndexOf(audio_id)` returns 279 .Why So? If you want further details, insist me so that i edit the post to add up relevant info.

Comment: The problem reported in above comment is actually my mistake, such that, `mainCursor` does contain only tracks whose colums `IS_MUSIC = 1`