# Android MediaStore TITLE_KEY is not reliable

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I am following the approach i got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930934/android-mediastore-get-cursor-position-by-comparing-with-title-key). But now new instability comes into play such that, TITLE_KEY is not seems to be as unique as it has to be.

Using below code,generated an array list containing TITLE_KEYs.

```
Cursor c = myService.getCursor;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String track_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Media.TITLE_KEY));
            list_key.add(audio_id);
        }
```

Now when i access

```
list_key.lastIndexOf(titleKeyStringToLookUp);
```

getting the last index if duplicated entries...

Now consider the case,

I have six different song, each different duration, but same ARTIST, same ALBUM. For this, the TITLE_KEYS are same, so that i can't distinguish `titleKeyStringToLookUp` indices which one out of this six songs.

So i need a way to resolve this problem due to duplicated `TITLE_KEYS` so that i would get the song index(in this case the one out of six songs)

Please help, Thank you all...

Comment: How did you end up resolving this? Did you use _id instead?

Comment: Yes, and that s the unique value in an sqllite database. Initially it was my misconception that title key would suffice